# Is there a way to create flutter stepper from a for loop and set active step?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am pulling some data from an API into a stepper widget. The data returns a list of categories and those categories has a list of questions. I would like to set the category name as a step and its questions for the content of the step.
This is how I get the categories and build the steps

```
  void _getCategories() async {
var res = await Network().getData("/questions");
//check if success
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  var body = json.decode(res.body);
  var data = body['flow']['categories'];
  HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  for (var category in data) {
    temp.putIfAbsent(category['description'], () => category['questions']);
  }
  setState(() {
    categories = temp;
  });
  _buildSteps();
}
}
```

Then I build a list of steps:

```
  void _buildSteps() {
categories.forEach((key, value) {
  steps.add(Step(
      title: Text(key), content: Text(key), isActive: currentStep >= 0));
});
```

}

using

```
currentStep >= 0
```

sets all the steps to active, but I only want to set the first step to be the current step and when click continue, it will set the next step to be active.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Step> getSteps() {
  List<Step> mySteps = [];
   for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
     final _step = Step(title: Text('$i'), content: Container(), isActive: true);
     mySteps.add(_step);
   }
   return mySteps;
}
```